# Decreasing limits

Tags: stacking-symbols, size, substack

I have the following codes. Is it possible to decrease the size of limits in minimum phrase? 
Thanks in advance.

‎

```
    \documentclass[12pt‎ , ‎a4paper]{article}‎
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \begin{document}

    ‎\begin{equation}‎‎
    \begin{aligned}
    ‎\min\limits_{‎‎\begin{aligned}‎‎‎
                 ‎j_{3}^{D_{f}}(\{  h_{r},h_{1},h_{2} \})‎, ‎\\ r \in \{ 3,4 \}‎‎         
                \end{aligned}}‎u_{11} & >   f(f-4)(f+1)-(f-4)(3+2(-3-2\sqrt{f})^{2})\\ 
 \phantom{{ }} &\qquad -\left[2(-3-2\sqrt{f})-3\right]^{2} \\
     \phantom{{ }}&\qquad ={f}^{3}-11{f}^{2}-24{f}^{\frac{3}{2}}-9f+24\sqrt {f}+3‎, 
    \end{aligned}
    ‎\end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `\substack`, but there's a little complication with such a big subscript: the second line of the alignment will be lowered to make room for the subscript.

There's a slick trick for avoiding this, using `\smash`; however, this would destroy the property of `\min` being of class `\mathop`, so we reinstate it around the `\smash`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}  
\begin{split}
\mathop{\smash[b]{\min_{
  \substack{
    j_{3}^{D_{f}}(\{h_{r},h_{1},h_{2} \}), \\ r \in \{ 3,4 \}}
  }
}} u_{11} & > f(f-4)(f+1)-(f-4)\bigl(3+2(-3-2\sqrt{f})^{2}\bigr)\\
          &\qquad -[2(-3-2\sqrt{f})-3]^{2} \\
          &={f}^{3}-11{f}^{2}-24{f}^{\frac{3}{2}}-9f+24\sqrt {f}+3 ,
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that

1. `\limits` is not needed
2. `\left[` and `\right]` did nothing good where you used them
3. `\phantom{{ }}` does nothing at all

I also used `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` for the outer parentheses in the first line and aligned the final `=` with `>`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:

```
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
   \min\limits_{\substack{
              j_{3}^{D_{f}}(\{  h_{r},h_{1},h_{2} \}), \\ r \in \{ 3,4 \}            }}u_{11} & >   f(f-4)(f+1)-(f-4)(3+2(-3-2\sqrt{f})^{2})\\[-8pt]
 \phantom{{ }} &\qquad -\left[2(-3-2\sqrt{f})-3\right]^{2} \\
     \phantom{{ }}&\qquad ={f}^{3}-11{f}^{2}-24{f}^{\frac{3}{2}}-9f+24\sqrt {f}+3,
    \end{aligned}\end{equation}
```